# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity Error - concerning time_select in formtastic?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm using the following code to create some timeslect and date select objects using activeadmin and formtastic. The result generates two timeselects and a date select object as the correspoinding data field types are time and date. The problem is that when I submit the form I get a ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity error

```
<%= f.inputs :class=>'inputs', :for=>Schedule.new do |fu| %>
  <%= fu.input :eta, :label=>"ETA", :ignore_date=>true %>
  <%= fu.input :etd, :label=>"ETD", :ignore_date=>true %>
  <%= fu.input :date, :ignore_time=>true %>
<% end %>
```

When posting the etd and eta fields are posted as arrays - is there a way to get the actual values of them cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for sure what your problem is without seeing the models in question, but my best guess is that you've got an issue with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `attr_accessible`.

On the model represented by the parent form, you will need:

```
has_one :schedule    #assuming it's has_one, could be something else...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedule
attr_accessible :schedule_details
```

Note that the association name in `attr_accessible` is appended with `_details`. If you just have the association name, Rails will throw an exception.

Does this look like it could be the issue?

Comment: Not really - the time_select fields return back an array and not the actual time values, I'm actually doing some custom actions on the post back from the controller here.